# Write and read a .ini file in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, text, ini, streamwriter

Let's say I have a Button that, when clicked, will output text ("test text") to a .ini file in directory (C:/configdir) for example. How would I create this .ini file?

Then I have another Button that, when clicked, will show the content ("test text") of the .ini I just created. I am guessing I need to streamwrite the text.

Comment: Yes.  This question is really "how do I read and write text files?".  The standard documentation should do : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx  and  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx   Have you tried these?  Did it not work?

Comment: Agree with @J..., the core of the question is about how to read/write plain text files.  If you really need to work with .INI files there are Win APIs designed specifically to do just that.  If you simply want to store a few values for in your application across runs then look at using [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx).

Comment: @Idle_Mind - yes, all good points.  This sounds like an XY problem.  "How do I write text to a file" -- why?  "Because I want an .ini file" -- why?  "Because I want to save user settings" oh...  Application settings are definitely the way to go if that's what you're after.  For the easy lead-in see : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wabtadw6.aspx

Comment: Yup your right! That worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something that will work.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\myfile.ini", False)
        sw.WriteLine("test text")
    End Using

    Using sr As New System.IO.StreamReader("c:\myfile.ini")
        Dim Line As String = sr.ReadLine
        Do While Line IsNot Nothing
            MsgBox(Line)
        Loop
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: For anyone reading this, please note that "ordinary" users may not have write access to the root of the C: drive and a better place is likely to be in one of the directories given in the [Environment.SpecialFolder Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and that using [My.Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saa62613.aspx) as indicated by J  in a now-dead link is an easy way to go.